# How to generate numbers in order from 1 to 10000 in groovy?

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I need to parameterize the script so that the numbers are used in order

Comment: What script? And what do you need to parametrize exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the range syntax to generate an array of in order numbers.

```
def countParam = 10000
​def range = 1..countParam

=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on your requirements, i.e. in what form and how you're going to use these numbers further.

Once of the possible options is using [`upto()` function](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Number.html#upto(java.lang.Number,%20groovy.lang.Closure)):

[image]

If you want comma-separated values for later storing in [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you can use a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instance like:

```
def numbers = new StringBuilder()
1.upto(1000) {
    numbers.append(it)
    if (it < 1000) {
        numbers.append(',')
    }
}

vars.put('numbers', numbers)
```

you will get:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10....1000
```

You may find [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) article useful.